# How do i make the ball fall from the TOP CENTER of the screen to the bottom

Tags: tkinter, timer, tkinter-canvas

I currently am working on a project where it just shows a cyan ball moving in a loop from the top of the canvas to the bottom of the canvas. I don't know what I seem to be doing wrong, I am a beginner in python and tkinter. Thank you for any and all help.

```
def moveDown():
    canvas.data.cy += 5
    if (canvas.data.cy + canvas.data.radius \>= canvasWidth ):
        canvas.data.cy = canvas.data.radius

def doTimerFired():
    moveDown()
    redrawAll()

def timerFired():
    doTimerFired()
    delay = canvas.data.delay  # milliseconds
    canvas.after(delay, timerFired) # pause, then call timerFired again

def redrawAll():
    canvas.delete(ALL)

    # draw the circle
    r = canvas.data.radius
    cx = canvas.data.cx
    cy = canvas.data.cy
    canvas.create_oval(cx-r, cy-r, cx+r, cy+r, fill="cyan") 

def init():
    canvas.data.radius = 10  
    canvas.data.cx = 10
    canvas.data.cy = 14
    canvas.data.delay = 100 #milliseconds

def run():
    # create the root and the canvas
    global canvas, canvasWidth, canvasHeight
    root = Tk()
    canvasWidth = 500
    canvasHeight = 500
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=canvasWidth, height=canvasHeight)
    canvas.pack()

    # Set up canvas data and call init
    class Struct: pass
    canvas.data = Struct()
    canvas.data.canvasWidth = canvasWidth
    canvas.data.canvasHeight = canvasHeight
    init()
    timerFired()

    # and launch the app
    root.mainloop()  # This call BLOCKS 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentaion.

Comment: I fixed the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i make the ball fall from the TOP CENTER of the screen to the
> bottom.

Typo error `\>= canvasWidth` should be `== canvasWidthin moveDown()` function.

To place the ball from the TOP CENTER of the screen to the bottom.

Add value in line 23:

```
cx = canvas.data.cx
```

to:

```
cx = canvas.data.cx+225
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ball to fall from the *top center* of the canvas, then you need to initialize `canvas.data.cx` to half the canvas width instead of 10 inside `init()`:

```py
def init():
    canvas.data.radius = 10
    canvas.data.cx = canvasWidth / 2  ### center of canvas horizontally
    canvas.data.cy = canvas.data.radius
    canvas.data.delay = 100 #milliseconds
```